# Django REST Framework organize Interactive API Docs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm auto-generating an API using [Django REST Framework's interactive API doc generation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.6-announcement/#interactive-api-documentation), but I'm coming across a little issue.

I have core entities like `cars` and `people` and there's a parent entity called `town`.

The routes to modify things look like `/api/town/<town pk>/cars/<car pk>`, but the way the interactive API docs render, I only see `town` originally

It renders kind of like this

```
town
  -- /api/town/<town pk>/cars/<car pk>
  -- /api/town/<town pk>/people/<person pk>
```

But the view is collapsed originally, so all you see at the start is

```
town
```

Does anybody know if there's a way to cluster things in individual groups, like

```
cars
  -- /api/town/<town pk>/cars/<car pk>
people
  -- /api/town/<town pk>/people/<person pk>
```

The initial view would then be

```
cars
people
```

which I think is a lot easier to understand, and more organized

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers) may help you .